# Why is this method showing an error in the if clause?

Tags: java, variables, methods, void

I am writing a void method that needs to change the value of stocklevel in my object part0. However, there shows an error when i try to write the logic.

AssembledStockLevel

```
public int calculateAvailForAssembly(){
    if(basica.getStockLevel() <= basicb.getStockLevel()){
        assembledstocklevel = basica.getStockLevel();
    } else { assembledstocklevel = basicb.getStockLevel();
    }
    return assembledstocklevel;
}
```

Code showing error

```
   public void changeStockLevel(){
    if(assembledstocklevel <= basica.getStockLevel()){
   [Error is here -->]basica.getStockLevel() = basica.getStockLevel() - assembledstocklevel;
    }
}
```

The error says left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable??

basica is a variable i made to refer to part0 object

Comment: what is assmembedstocklevel?

Comment: just updated. empty variable that get assigned in calculateAvailForAssembly() method

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax. Your left-hand side is a method invocation, not a variable.

Comment: Same code base question from you few hours ago [Trouble with setter method and returning getter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161946/trouble-with-setter-method-and-returning-getter).

Comment: it's not the same. that question was based on trying to get the assembledstocklevel. This one is changing the stocklevel of part objects not the assembledstocklevel

Answer (score 2):

`basica.getStockLevel()` returns a reference to a value. You can't assign anything to that reference. You should have a setter method for stock level and use it to update its value.

Something like:

```
basica.setStockLevel(basica.getStockLevel() - assembledstocklevel)
```

Comment: i've put that in, but realised I don't think I want the method void? There is no change to basica (part0) stocklevel. This is oh so confusing lol

Comment: @danielb I lost you there :(

Answer (score 2):

You're using a reference to set a value, use a setter method.

```
basica.setStockLevel(basica.getStockLevel() - assembledstocklevel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign anything to a method. You have set through a setter method like :

```
basica.setStockLevel(basica.getStockLevel() - assembledstocklevel)
```